# How to check if a Word table cell is filled/empty through Excel VBA and copying the content to Excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

For work, I need to be able to pass through several Word files and gather data in a table (always the same in each file) to send its data to the Excel table for, later, making costs calculations.

All this is written in Excel VBA as there is only 1 excel file for several Word files

I have a nice messy background in VBA, but it's the first time I try to "use word through Excel".

I tried several standard Word functions, like `Selection.Information(wdWithInTable)` to know if the cursor is actually in a table, but absolutely nothing happens. I must have missed something..

I let you check the code here after, I indicated in the comments what works and what don't

```
Public Function WriteData(Fil)  'This function gathers the data inside the word document and put them in the excel table. "Fil" simply got the folder's path

Dim oApp        As Object 'Word.Application
Dim oDoc        As Object 'Word.Document
Dim sDocName    As String

On Error Resume Next
    Set oApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application") 'See if word is already running
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then     'Word isn't running so start it
        Set oApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    End If
On Error GoTo 0 'edited here
                                                                                    oApp.Visible = True
    FilAdress = Fil
    Set oDoc = oApp.Documents.Open(FilAdress)

        With oApp.Selection.Find       'Searching for the key word permitting to end up in the table
            .Text = "Repair Code"
            .Forward = True
            .MatchWholeWord = False
        End With

        RCodeFind = oApp.Selection.Find.Execute      'this works
        If RCodeFind = True Then
            oApp.Selection.MoveDown     'this works

'Here, i tried some random things...
            oApp.Selection.homekey     'this works
            oApp.Selection.Select     'this don't work :(
            oApp.Selection.endof     'this works

            Test = oApp.paragraph.Range.Tables.Count      'this don't work :(
            oApp.Selection.Selectcell     'this works !!!
            Test = oApp.Selection.Information(wdWithInTable)'this don't work

        End If

        test01 = oApp.ActiveDocument.Tables.Count     'this work
        Test = oApp.ActiveDocument.Selection.Cells.Next     'this don't work


        oApp.ActiveDocument.Selection.Move Unit:=wdCell, Count:=1     'this don't work


End Function
```

I've indicated all the lines that don't work, when "it should" as I followed what I read on different pages about Word VBA and Word VBA through Excel...

I noticed that in lines like the last one`oApp.ActiveDocument.Selection.Move Unit:=wdCell, Count:=1`, the first part works correctly, but the `Unit:=wdCell, Count:=1` isn't even considered...

May someone give me a hint on why some functions work and some other not?

Thanks by advance !

Comment: As a first step, I would advise resetting the error detection. You are using `On Error Resume Next` to detect whether Word is already running. That's fine: but you should set it back to `On Error Goto 0` afterwards. As it currently stands, no errors will be detected for the rest of the script - which can hinder your ability to debug.

Comment: @CindyMeister It's done, so, the error is a "bad parameter" for, for instance, the line 'oApp.ActiveDocument.Selection.Move Unit:=wdCell, Count:=1'. If I put away the parameters at the end (Unit:=wdCell, Count:=1), it works/don't bug. Also, at all the lines where I wrote "Test = something", the variable "Test" stays as "Empty"... (I'm trying to continue to work, but that's becoming more and more annoying, I'd like to simply use the Word VBA functions ^^, )

Comment: OK... First thing to think about is the *objects* to be manipulated. Ask yourself: Do they belong to the document, or the Word application? Then be sure to use `oDoc` for the former and `oApp` for the latter. Next, for the moment, add a reference to the Word object model (Tools/References in the VBA editor), and change the declaration from `As Object` to what is currently commented out. This will give you Intellisense so that you can immediately see if what you want to type is recognized. Later, when the code works, you can remove the reference and change back to `Object`.

Comment: This won't work - `oApp.Selection.Select` because there's no reason to select a selection - it's already selected. This can't work - `Test = oApp.paragraph.Range.Tables.Count` because a paragraph cannot contain a table. Try `oDoc.Tables.Count`.

Comment: For the rest of the "doesn't work" comments choose **one** and describe *how* it doesn't work. We don't know what you expect...

Comment: To test whether a table cell is "empty" test how many characters it contains (the `Len` function). A Word table is *never* "empty" - it always contains at least one character (ANSI 13 - a paragraph mark). So if the length is <= 1 it's "empty".

Comment: @CindyMeister Well, before anything, thank's for your time :)
Concerning the oDoc and oApp, I'm quite lost... You tell me to change the second line for `Dim oDoc        As Word.Document`? But that later it will be useless and I'll be able to put "Object" back in place?
I've done this change, and tried to use the oDoc in place of oApp at the places that seemed the good ones, but it create an error immediately `object variable not set` (I also changed the `oDoc = oApp.Documents.Open(FilAdress)` for a `Vari  = oApp.Documents.Open(FilAdress)`... 
in fact, I have no idea of how this all can work

Comment: Typically, a line like `RCodeFind = oApp.Selection.Find.Execute` works... But it concerns the document and not the application --> `RCodeFind = oDoc.Selection.Find.Execute` ---> Bug... Do I need to keep the line `oDoc = oApp.Documents.Open(FilAdress)`? I mean, it's just made to open the word document; I don't need that anymore, once the file is open...

Comment: `Set oDoc = ...` without `Set` it can't work. `As Word.Document` will never be "useless". `As Object` is often used so that the code can be distributed among people who may have different versions of Office. At this point, given the lack of experience, it might be best to read a lot of code samples here and in other places that run Word from Excel. The object being to try to understand what's happening (and why). We're happy to help, here, but this isn't a tutorial site...

Comment: @CindyMeister I agree that it's not a tutorial site and you're not a teacher (not here at least ^^,). But I struggle to find anything on the internet about using Word through Excel... Do you know where I can find some nice explanation on this subject?

Comment: Not right off-hand, but try googling: tutorial Excel word vba - I haven't looked at any of the links, but the search brings up quite a few things which look like they could help... (Not here, no, but I do teach :-))

Comment: @CindyMeister "Excel Word VBA"... Why was I searching for something more complex than that... And giving less results? *Palmface* Thank's for everything ;-)

Comment: hope the information gets you a step or two further. If you run into more specific questions don't hesitate to ask!